# Google Admin Kiosk Mode JSON Configuration

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-admin-sdk

I am looking to do a Google Chomebook kiosk for chromebooks and I am running into the issue of how the app runs. As the issue is we want people to sign in but after some time of inactivity to restart the app. I feel like this is a normal function of a kiosk.

We are also trying to get the app to ask where the person wants to save the documents as well as an optional USB downloand.

Currently I am stuck trying to find correct JSON values for all of this and their isn't much documentation on this.

```
        {
  "kioskModeApp": {
    "appId": "chrome",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive",
    "clearCache": true,
    "clearCookies": true,
    "clearData": {
      "since": "forever"
    }
  },
  "kioskModeAppTimeout": {
    "idleTimeSeconds": 20,
    "refreshTimeSeconds": 10
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it depends if you are using a Chrome App or a PWA. You can see some of the information for Chrome apps (Deprecated): [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/#platform_apps_apis) and for the migration to PWA [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/migration/). It also has a blog where you can ask more information about the Kiosk app JSON configuration [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/)

Comment: How can I read this key value pair within my application? I want to add some key value pair in managed configuration and based on that, I would want my application to be authenticated and navigated.